# Laravel 5.2 redirect()->back()->withErrors $errors is empty

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

> I'm trying to apply a validation in my auth form. Everything works well, until I go into my return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);, where the redirect()->back()->withErrors() isn't storing the error in the MessageBag (making my $errors variable empty for my view).
>
> laravel.blade.php

```
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN FORM -->
        <form class="login-form" action="{{ url('/login') }}" method="post">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <h3 class="form-title font-green">Iniciar sesión</h3>
                @if (count($errors) > 0) // Here is where i check and my $errors variable is empty
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            <span>{{ $error }}</span>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Usuario" name="email" value="{{ (isset($email) ? $email : '' ) }}" /> </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" /> </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn green uppercase">Iniciar sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- END LOGIN FORM -->
```

> AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}

/**
 * Get the failed login message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
{
    return Lang::has('auth.failed')
            ? Lang::get('auth.failed')
            : 'These credentials do not match our records.';
}
```

Comment: Why not try `->withErrors();`

Comment: Because it is a custom error. 
`->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
]);   //  it returns "These credentials do not match our records."`

Comment: if you 'hardcode' `$this->loginUsername()` with some string like `'john'` what happens?

Comment: Still empty. I put {{ dd($errors) }} at the end of my login.blade.php and this is what shows:

`ViewErrorBag {#211 ▼
  #bags: []
}`

Comment: Surely the withErrors method should accept a key => value pair where the key is the form field, right?

Comment: Is it definitely failing? What happens if the user logs in?

Comment: It is. If the user log in with correct credentials `$this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);` is called and everything is fine. I'm just having troubles with the $errors storage when -`redirect()->back()->withErrors` happen.

Comment: Cool just checking as it doesn't make sense that it's failing and there are no errors

Comment: Yeah, I felt the same way. Thank you for your time, haakym.

Comment: I can confirm, using Laravel 5.4.36, the same bug happens. A workaround is to not use `return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);` but `return redirect('/login')->withErrors($validator);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hello You have have to write as below redirect()

```
 return redirect()->back()->with('status-keyword', 'error message');
```

and on front end you get that message using

```
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger text-center msg" id="error">
    <strong>{{ session('error') }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

I hope that this will fruitful to you.
Thank You.